# Input type into Linear4bit is torch.float16, but bnb_4bit_compute_type=torch.float32 (default). This will lead to slow inference or training speed

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, llama

I am trying to run Llama 2.0 on my computer with server and it warns me that my speed is going to be less as I am making some mistake which I am unaware of, however, it works and I dont know how to optimize it

following is the functional code

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import torch 

class LlamaChatBot:
    def __init__(self, model_name ="daryl149/llama-2-7b-chat-hf"):
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()
            self.isGPU = torch.cuda.is_available()
            self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
            if self.isGPU:
                self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
                self.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
                    model_name,
                    device_map='auto', load_in_4bit=True
                )
            else:
                self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("daryl149/llama-2-7b-chat-hf")
                self.model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name).to(self.device)

    def generate_response(self, prompt):
        if self.isGPU():
            input_ids = self.tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to('cuda')
        else: input_ids = self.tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
        generated_ids = self.model.generate(input_ids, max_length=1024)
        generated_text = self.tokenizer.decode(generated_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
        print(generated_text)

        return generated_text
```

warning :

```
  warnings.warn(f'Input type into Linear4bit is torch.float16, 
                but bnb_4bit_compute_type=torch.float32 (default).
                 This will lead to slow inference or training speed.')
```

Hardware :

```
Dell Precision T7920 Tower server/Workstation
Intel xeon gold processor @ 18 cores 2.3 ghz dual 36 cores 72 virtual cpus 
512GB DDR4 RAM 
UPGRADABLE UPTO 3TB RAM
512GB SSD HDD FOR BOOTING
7TB SATA HDD FOR STORAGE 
24GB RTX 3090 DDR6 GRAPHICS CARD
```

Answer (score 13):

You can find the solution in the next  [Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ge2F1QSK8Q7h0hn3YKuBCOAS0bK8E0wf#scrollTo=VPD7QS_DR-mw), use something like:

```
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
load_in_4bit=True,
bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)
```

When you load your model using  from_pretrained() Transformers method:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, quantization_config=bnb_config, device_map="auto")
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably also set bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16 in your from_pretrained() function when load the model.

Comment: It should be `torch_dtype` instead of `bnb_4bit_compute_dtype` for the `from_pretrained()` function.